# django forms client side validation?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a library/app which will help to easily implement a client side validation in django ?

I found many form layout/display libraries like

1. django-uni-form
2. django-crispy-forms

etc but none of them have a client side validation. Can any one point to a good framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [django-helpers](https://bitbucket.org/ajumell/django_helpers/) (I am the author of the library). There is a form renderer app which will generate the form in a easily fancy bootstrap template and also implements client side validations for some validators using jquery validation plugin. Its still under development. There are no much docs but check the examples. Its easy to understand.

Comment: Does this one implement regular expression validation and date/time validation ?

Comment: not all regular expression validations are implemented. email, url, numeric validations are implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Sorry about privet repo. check this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-helpers

Comment: Would you be up for making the repo public having a public mirror ?

Answer (score 6):

Check `Django-parsley`.

https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley

It uses parsleyjs.

http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html